# Convert XML into another XML using XSLT(number conversion)

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert XML into another XML using XSLT. 
This is my input XML:

```
...
<size>21467</size>
....
```

I would like to convert this input XML into output XML which looks like this:

```
...
<HAS>
<C SZ="21k"/>
</HAS>
...
```

My XSLT code:

```
...
<HAS>
<C>
<xsl:attribute name="SZ" select="xs:string(xs:anyURI(fn:string($var1_resultof_first/size)))" />
</C>
</HAS>
..
```

I'm not sure how to convert size "21467" to round off to "21k". Any help would be appreciated

Comment: One example is not enough to express a rule. Will the given value always be greater than 1,000? If not, what should be the result then?

Comment: I already have a template <xsl:template match="/"> which applies to all the elements. I cannot use two templates. Is there any other way that I can do this? I have number greater than 1,000

Comment: "*I cannot use two templates.*" You can use as many templates as necessary. In any case, that's not the essential part here. `format-number($input div 1000, '0k')` is. Use it as you will.

Comment: Please check the edit part of my question. I have added my original XSLT

Comment: I think you have enough to figure this on your own. Next time, post a [mcve] including the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following template:

```
<xsl:template match="size">
    <HAS>
        <C SZ="{format-number(. div 1000, '0k')}"/>
    </HAS>
</xsl:template>
```

applied to your input example, will return:

```
<HAS>
   <C SZ="21k"/>
</HAS>
```